# Formatting related with SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a question regarding SSRS.
I have issues with formatting, I have a column that have a value like 1-5, Less than 1, >100 in my SSRS.
The issue is WHEN YOU EXPORT TO CSV ALL RECORDS THAT HAS A VALUE 1 - 5 CHANGED TO 5 - JAN.
From sql, excel all are perfect. The is issue is regarding csv export.
Is there any one who have an idea.
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the CSV Export. If you open the csv file in a simple text editor, you will see the data as you expected ("1-5").

I assume you are opening the CSV file in Excel.

Excel is interpreting the text as a date. If you change the column formatting to general/text in Excel it should display correctly.

Comment: Thank you Alan, But the report is already embedded to portal and when you download or export the report by default it is in csv that the issue too

Comment: so what does it look like if you open the csv file in a a text editor?

Comment: So that proves my point. It is an issue with how Excel interprets the data, not an issue with the CSV export.

Comment: yeah i think spacing in a value may solve the issue in tablix ssrs